# Jump to top when click on links with hashtags + text

Tags: javascript, html

I have links with the following syntax:

```
<div class="footer">
    <a href="page#link1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="page#link2">Link 2</a>
    <a href="page#link3">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

When I'm on the `http://example.com/page` and I click on any of the 3 links, it doesn't jump to the top of the page.

However, it jumps if the link is something like this:

```
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
```

How should I make it scroll/jump to the top when any of the links are clicked?

Comment: The question is, why would you want to do that? You're basically describing some sort of an anti/dark-pattern, because the string trailing the `#` character actually tells the browser to navigate to the element whose ID matches it when the page loads (if said element is present on load). If you want to remove that behaviour, strip the URL hash out from the `href` attribute.

Comment: A hashtag is a means of indicating that a term, in plain text, should be hyperlinked to a search engine on social media networks. It gets the name because it it uses a hash character to prefix it. Please don’t confuse other uses of the hash character with hashtags.

Comment: What's with the negative voting!! I need the URL structure since I'm using Bootstrap tabs and that's how it can link to the individual tabs. I cannot change the URL pattern.

Comment: I down voted because of several reasons: (1) there is insufficient details in your answer, like how you only mentioned you're using Bootstrap tabs in the comments, but not in the main question itself. I felt that it didn't warrant a close vote, because you did provide some code, and some semblance of a desired behaviour, although vague and incomplete. (2) You are describing an anti-pattern that I don't agree with, unless otherwise better explained. I am more than happy to retract the vote, if the question's quality is improved upon. Including an MCVE will greatly help.

Comment: @Terry The OP never stated that she wanted to or was using the `href=#` approach as a final solution. In fact, that was the entire point of the question, to find a different/better way to accomplish the end-result. This being the case, Your #2 reason for down voting is not applicable. Also, how does the use of Bootstrap, change the solution? This means that your #1 reason for the down vote may not be applicable either.

Comment: @ScottMarcus That's your opinion. And even if point #2 doesn't stand, #1 is still a perfectly legit reason for a close vote.

Comment: How is it my opinion that the OP doesn't want to use the `href=#` method? The question clearly states that the OP already knows that `href=#` works and then goes on to ask how to do the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a click event handler for all the elements you want to cause the scroll to occur using **[`window.ScrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)** like this:

```js
// Get a node list of all the elements that use the footer class
var footers = document.querySelectorAll(".footer");

// Loop through the footers and set up a click event handler for each
for(var i = 0; i < footers.length; i++){
  footers[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){    
    // Scroll to the top of the page:
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });
}
```

```html
<a href="page#link1"><div class="footer">Link 1</div></a>
<a href="page#link2">Link 2</a>
<a href="page#link3"><div class="footer">Link 3</div></a>
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I don't know why there are negative down-voting to my question. It's a genuine question.

Comment: btw, it works but this breaks my Bootstrap Tabs!! Is there a possibility to run this script within a certain div class? 3 of these links are within a <div class="footer">